# Is there a way to use SAS error handling to write to/create a table

Tags: sas

I am trying to write some code which when the process errors a control table will be updated with certain values.

For the moment I have the following but gives a warning creating a work table called error_table and a column called status but no values. I have simplified the table I'm trying to create.

```
`%macro error_check;
%if &syserr > 0 %then %do;
%put This process has errored with the following message: &syserrortext;
%put Writing out status "error" to control table;
data error_table;
status = error;
run;
%end;
%else %do;
%put it is fine;
%end;
%mend;`
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to get the code working. This is the first time I've used the &syserr macro so I'm wondering if I'm using it wrong should be using some other method. Thanks for any help one can give.

Comment: What is it that you want to store into the variable STATUS?  Currently you are trying to assign it the value of a variable named ERROR, but since there is no variable with that name you get two variables that both have missing values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the string ERROR into a variable then do that.

```
status = "ERROR" ;
```

Without the quotes the string ERROR would be seen as a variable name.

If you want the value of the SYSERRORTEXT macro variable then use SYMGET() function.

```
status = symget('syserrortext');
```

Or just use the SYSMSG() function.

```
status = sysmsg();
```